# How to select dgvRow by rightClick?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a contextMenu on a DataGridView.

It shows options for manipulating with selectedRow.

User must have leftClick - to selecet a row - and then rightClick - to open contextMenu.

I want to omit leftClic, i.e. - select a dgvRow by rightClick and at the same time - open contextMenu.

Is it possible ?

Comment: This is relatively easy, but at the same time it's not simple, you will want to use the hittest method from the datagridview, I supplied you with a a working sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go try this.

add to your datagridview_MouseDown event

```
    private void dgvPermit_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo Hti;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Hti = dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (Hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                if (!((DataGridViewRow)(dgv.Rows[Hti.RowIndex])).Selected)
                {
                    dgv.ClearSelection();
                    ((DataGridViewRow)dgv.Rows[Hti.RowIndex]).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're really a Maestro.
I have not enough reputation for voting but... Thanks_a_Lot.